# Is $x^p+a$ always irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

As in the title. My first thought would be something using Fermat's little theorem, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: It's not when $a=0$.

Comment: What about for non-zero $a$?

Comment: It's not when $a=1$.

Comment: I screwed up the question, it should have been $+a$, my apologies

Comment: It's still not when $a=1$.

Comment: We always have $x^p+a\equiv (x+a)^p\pmod p$ so your polynomial is never irreducible.

Comment: @lulu, that's answer.